# Retrieve action name that comes request

Tags: asp.net-mvc

is it possible to retrieve action name from `HttpContext.Request` which that request came.
I already know that I can get `HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer`but I want to know what was the previous action.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use TempData or HiddenFields and store the previous Controller and Action. Request object doesn't hold anything (except UrlReferer) to keep track of old Action and Controller.

You can do some string manipulations on UrlReferer to parse it and get to know about previous controller action. But I am not going to suggest that way. Remember UrlReferer can easily manipulated.

Using TempData is one way for server to keep track of data for individual request. You can also use HiddenFields to store the same information. But that decision between TempData and HiddenFields is to be taken on the grounds of how secure and important that this (Previous controller and action) information is going to be for application.

Between you can get present Action and Controller values using -

```
ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"];
ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["Action"];
```